# pasar filtros a store procedure sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente store procedure en sql server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ConsultaRentabilidadLocal]  
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @fechaini int = 0, 
    @fechafin int = 0,  
    @id_almacen int = 0 

AS

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT distinct(al.id_almacen), al.des_almacen, al.canalventa, al.cadenaventa, sum(T1.descuento_yld_ac) as des_yld,
    sum(T1.margen_yld_ac) as margen_yld, SUM(T1.venta_ytd) as venta_ytd, sum(T1.venta_yld_ac) as venta_yld, sum(T1.venta_proy) as ppto_ytd, 
    sum(T1.unidades_ytd) as uni_ytd, sum(T1.unidades_yld_ac) as uni_yld, sum(T1.unidades_proy) as uni_proy, sum(T1.documentos_proy) as boletas_ppto, 
    sum(T1.documentos_ytd) as boletas_ytd, sum(T1.documentos_yld_ac) as boletas_yld, sum(T1.margen_proy) as margen_ppto, sum(T1.margen_ytd) as margen_ytd, 
    sum(T1.descuento_ytd) as des_ytd, 
    (SELECT sum(val_trafico_ytd) FROM fact.trafico_comparada_extendida as T WHERE T.id_almacen = al.id_almacen AND id_calendario between @fechaini and @fechafin) as trafico_ytd ,
    (SELECT sum(val_trafico_ppto) FROM fact.trafico_comparada_extendida as T WHERE T.id_almacen = al.id_almacen AND id_calendario between @fechaini and @fechafin) as trafico_ppto ,
    (SELECT sum(val_trafico_yld_ac) FROM fact.trafico_comparada_extendida as T WHERE T.id_almacen = al.id_almacen AND id_calendario between @fechaini and @fechafin) as trafico_yld 
FROM dim.almacen as al 
    LEFT JOIN fact.venta_comparada_empleado_producto as T1 ON T1.id_almacen = al.id_almacen  

WHERE T1.id_calendario BETWEEN @fechaini and @fechafin AND 
    ( ( ((al.des_almacen like 'FE%') OR ( al.des_almacen like 'MM%' ) OR (al.des_almacen like 'BA%' ) OR (al.des_almacen like 'NM%') ) AND 
    al.cod_almacen NOT IN('FE102', 'FE120', 'FE130', 'NM201','NM207', 'NM209','NM219', 'MM029', 'MM033', 'MM034', 'MM038', 'MM045', 'CE017', 'CE104') AND 
    (al.id_almacen > 22 OR al.cod_almacen IN ('BA086','BA087') ) ) )  

GROUP BY al.canalventa, al.cadenaventa, al.id_almacen, al.des_almacen 
ORDER BY al.canalventa, al.cadenaventa, al.des_almacen

END
```

pero necesito pasarle filtros y tablas adicionales, estoy tratando de agregar lo que necesito declarándolo como text pero me da error de sintaxis y no me guarda las modificaciones, por ejemplo, estoy añadiendo Después de id_almacen:

```
@id_almacen int = 0,
@filtro text,
@from text
```

Y:

```
LEFT JOIN fact.venta_comparada_empleado_producto as T1 ON T1.id_almacen = 
al.id_almacen  
     @from
```

antes del WHERE pero me arroja error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ConsultaRentabilidadLocal, Line
>   32 [Batch Start Line 7] Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '@from'.

Necesito hacer ésto o no se de que otra forma hacerlo para que me reciba filtros desde el php como por ejemplo:

```
 if(!empty($request['marca'])){
                $filtro .= " AND p.cod_marca like '". $request['marca']."' ";
            }
            if(!empty($request['clase'])){
                $filtro .= " AND p.cod_clase like '". $request['clase']."' ";
            }
            if(!empty($request['familia'])){
                $filtro .= " AND p.cod_familia like '". $request['familia']."' ";
            }
```

Y no puedo hacerlo con una vista porque se tarda demasiado la consulta, mientras que son un store procedure, la consulta básica se hace de manera mas rápida.

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Podrias mostar al final como lo estas dejando, cuando te marca el error

Comment: No puedes usar una variable como parte del `FROM`, esa es la explicación del error. La única forma es que el SP cree una sentencia dinámica, y viendo la complejidad de la consulta no te lo recomiendo, preferible hacer distintas versiones del mismo Sp para cada tabla. Con los filtros se puede jugar en el SQL si el parámetro llega en NULL no aplicamos el filtro: `AND (@marca IS NULL or p.cod_marca LIKE @marca)`

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo es abrir tu código a inyección de SQL. Podrías seguir el consejo de Patricio Moracho, pero necesitarías usar `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` al final del SELECT.

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas.  Estoy tratando de armar el sql con todos los parámetros null en un principio, hay alguna manera de poder "imprimir" por pantalla el sql que se va armando dentro del store procedure para saber qué y cómo se estàn armando los parámetros?